# Can we use hover effect in mobile using flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, hover, solution

I need hover effect in my icon using flutter, but I want this hover effect on my mobile

Comment: I think In mobile you use the 'splash' effect instead of hover, hover is used for web , for this purpose you can used 'InkWell' widget  [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are no mouse devices on mobile, so users don't have the luxury of using hover effects. Using a hover effect on mobile apps causes buttons to stay stuck in the hovered state when tapped. This stickiness not only confuses users, but it frustrates them when they're forced to double-tap buttons to initiate an action.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use something like this:

```
MouseRegion(
      cursor: hoverStatus ? SystemMouseCursors.click : SystemMouseCursors.basic,
      onEnter: (event) {
        setState(() {
          hoverStatus = true;
        });
      },
      onExit: (event) {
        setState(() {
          hoverStatus = false;
        });
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPressStart: (details) {
          setState(() {
            hoverStatus = true;
          });
        },
        onLongPressEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            hoverStatus = false;
          });
        },
        onLongPressCancel: () {
          setState(() {
            hoverStatus = false;
          });
        },
    child: child,
    ),
),
```

`child` widget then updates to whatever functionality it is that you require. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the flutter **InkWell** widget, it is really simple and explainatory